# Property 'rawValue' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement' error while using typescript with cleave.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, cleave

I am having the above error in onChange event while using cleave with typescript. Ts throws error stating it doesn't have 'rawValue' in event.target.
My code is as below:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { StyledCleaveInput } from './style';
import { getCleaveOptions } from './helper';

interface Props {
  error?: string;
  id?: string;
  value?: string;
  onChange?: (arg: any) => any;
  disabled?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
  deviceType?: string;
  additional?: object;
}

const FormattedNumberInput: React.FC<Props> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  const { id, placeholder, onChange, error, disabled, deviceType, value } = props;

  type cleaveState = {
    setRawValue: (arg: any) => any
  };

  const [cleave, setCleave] = useState<cleaveState | null>(null);

  const options = useMemo(() => getCleaveOptions(props), []);

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if(onChange){
        onChange(event.target.rawValue);
      }
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cleave && value) cleave.setRawValue(value);
  }, [cleave, value]);

  return (
    <StyledCleaveInput
      data-id={id}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      isError={error}
      disabled={disabled}
      deviceType={deviceType}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
      onInit={setCleave}
    />
  );
};

FormattedNumberInput.propTypes = {
  error: PropTypes.string,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  deviceType: PropTypes.string,
  additional: PropTypes.object,
};

export default FormattedNumberInput;
```

Error is in:   event.target.rawValue of handleChange
StyledCleaveInput imported above uses 'cleave.js' Input and hence we can have event.target.rawValue inside the event object available in onChange of input.
Installed @@types/cleave also but error is still there.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Are you using a library to mean that an input would have the property `rawValue`? By default, inputs have the `value` property

Comment: yes, by using that library , gives rawValue in the event.target.  The above is a working code in js which I am converting to ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after researching a lot, I got the answer as implementing my own ChangeEvent like this:

```
interface ChangeEvent<T> extends React.ChangeEvent<T> {
  target: { rawValue: string } & EventTarget & T;
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if(onChange){
        onChange(event.target.rawValue);
      }
    },
    [onChange]
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. It would be good if Cleave had a built-in solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are making use of the [Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) library. In that case, for the `handleChange` event handler method, you should not be using `HTMLInputElement` as the type parameter for `ChangeEvent`. Instead, you might need to use `Cleave` (or any equivalent, as I am not too familiar with this library) as the type parameter.

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
  (event: React.ChangeEvent<Cleave>) => {
    if(onChange){
      onChange(event.target.rawValue);
    }
  },
  [onChange]
);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the solution but doing this, I am still getting error as " Cannot find name 'Cleave'." Tried importing Cleave here but that is not the something that is to be used as type

Comment: How about this instead? `React.ChangeEvent<typeof Cleave>`

Comment: Hey. doing the above change again gives a new type of warning as "Property 'rawValue' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & ComponentClass '."

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to use an Interface, you can also use [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to extend the HTMLInputElement type like so:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement & { rawValue: string }>) => {
      if(onChange){
        onChange(event.target.rawValue);
      }
    },
    [onChange]
  );
```